# Pronunciation difference b/w Python and Pyramid

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

Why is "Python" pronounced differently than "Pyramid"? Is there a logic behind why the "PY" is pronounced differently in both?

Comment: It's *py* vs. *pyr.*

Comment: There is no logic in the English language, although there might be reasons from etymology. Teaching material presents rules but they are only guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

When pronounced as a vowel letter, "Y" is generally equivalent to "I" and has the same two main pronunciations: "short i", the vowel found in the [word "KIT"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_set#Standard_lexical_sets_for_English), transcribed in [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) as /ɪ/, and "long i", the diphthong found in the word "PRICE", transcribed in IPA as /aɪ/.

The pronunciation of *python* and *pyramid* is consistent with the following [tendencies for vowel pronunciation in words derived from Latin or Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin):

- a vowel letter tends to take its "long" pronunciation when stressed and followed by a single written consonant and a single unstressed syllable. *Python* is followed by "th" (for the sake of this rule, the digraph "th" counts as a single consonant) and there is only one unstressed syllable after the stressed syllable.
- a vowel letter tends to take its "short" pronunciation when stressed and followed by more than one syllable. *Pyramid* has two unstressed syllables after the stressed syllable.

There are many exceptions to these tendencies, so they are not rules.

In the case of *pyramid,* the following /r/ sound can modify the quality of the preceding vowel, but that doesn't substantially affect the logic of how the pronunciation relates to the spelling.